# Wordpress custom taxonomy description for each post?

Tags: php, html, taxonomy

In a Wordpress blog, I'd like to put the term description of a specific custom taxonomy in the footer of each article.

Is this possible? I've tried

```
<?php term_description( $term_id, $taxonomy ) ?>
```

but no luck. Unless I'm using it incorrectly? When used, nothing shows up.

Comment: OK, and what's in your $term_id, $taxonomy?

Comment: Well, $term_id is different from post to post. The $taxonomy would be consistent, in this case it's projects.

Answer (score 6):

sounds like a silly question but are you echo'ing it out?

```
<?php echo term_description($term_id, $taxonomy); ?>
```

otherwise you'll need to get the current post's terms (where `my_term` is your custom taxonomy):

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'my_term' )
```

then get the description for the first term in ther array:

```
echo term_description($terms[0]->term_id, 'my_term');
```

I've not tested this but it should put you in the right direction.

So here's the full code below (should go in the single.php or loop.php or wherever your single post is created)...paste it inside the loop:

```
    <?php $my_taxonomy = 'projects'; // set this to whatever your custom taxonomy is called

$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $my_taxonomy ); // this gets all the terms attached to the post for your custom taxonomy

echo term_description($terms[0]->term_id, $my_taxonomy); // this displays the description for the first term in the $terms array ?>
```

Hope it helps,

Dave

Comment: Hmm, okay. Thank you. But how exactly do I put this all together? I'm still pretty new to PHP.

Comment: ok well assuming you are familiar with the WordPress loop all you need to do is place the above code wherever you want **inside the loop** (ive updated the answer)

Comment: also edited as I posted the wrong function, and I've also added 'projects' as the taxonomy :-)

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working for me.
Here's what I have in the single.php file:
<?php get_header(); ?>
 <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php $my_taxonomy = 'projects'; 
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $my_taxonomy ) ?>

  <article <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

   <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

   <div class="entry">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
   </div>

<?php echo term_description($terms[0]->term_id, $my_taxonomy); ?>
</article><?php endwhile; ?>


<?php get_footer(); ?>

Comment: Hi Scott, no worries. I've tried the above code and its works spot on for me? Could you show me how you're creating the custom taxonomy? Think that might be the issue. You also need an `endif;` just before you call `get_footer`. I missed a `;` out the code above so ive updated it again.

Comment: Weird! The endif; is there, I just had to delete a bunch of things to get it to fit in the comment limit.

This is how my taxonomies are made:

 function create_my_taxonomies() {

      register_taxonomy('projects', 'post', array(
            'hierarchical' => false, 'label' => 'Projects',
            'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true));
  }
  add_action('init', 'create_my_taxonomies', 0);

Comment: I should also add, when I just type in the echo term_description code manually, it works perfectly fine.